# Material-UI DataGrid: How do I add a tooltip to each row cell?

Tags: datagrid, material-ui

I could not find anything related to this in the react material ui datagrid documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/). I noticed you can add tooltips to columns via a "description" field, but can not find any documentation or examples related to rows.

Comment: I am looking for this too. This is an important feature for me. Very helpful when cell text is longer than the predefined column width.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

modify columns to add renderCell  attribute

```
const columns: Columns = [
  {
    field: 'id',
    headerName: 'ID',
    sortable: false,
    renderCell: (params: any) =>  (
       <Tooltip title={params.data.id} >
        <span className="table-cell-trucate">{params.data.id}</span>
        </Tooltip>
      ),
  }
]
```

css changes :

```
.table-cell-trucate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see `params.data` but i do see `params.row` and `params.getValue('someValue')` also works if `someValue` is not rendered in any column but exists on the input data object

Comment: Any solution for adding a tooltip to the row instead of the cell?

Comment: **params.data** does not seem to be available anymore in the current data grid version (currently "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.5.1"). Replacing **params.data.id** with **params.value.toString()** worked for me though

Comment: We should use params.row.id

Comment: appreciate having the CSS for retaining the custom ellipses with the renderCell

Comment: Problem with this solution is that you get a mix of tooltip and cell title aria-label hover "popups" which are styled differently, if you don' add the <Tooltip> to all cells. A better solution would maybe be to style the aria-label which is based on the cells title text, dynamically for each cell.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the columns like this:

```
 const editColumns = columns.map((column) => ({
    field: column,
    headerName: column,
    width:75,
    flex: 1,
    renderCell: (params: any) => (
      <Tooltip title={params.value}>
        <span>{params.value}</span>
      </Tooltip>
    ),
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just debug your code on rendercell and check what data you are getting in params, according to that filter your code.

```
renderCell: (params) =>  (
              <Tooltip title={params.value} >
               <span className="csutable-cell-trucate">{params.value}</span>
               </Tooltip>
             ),
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the default mui Row into the Tooltip

```js
import React from 'react'
import { DATA_GRID_DEFAULT_SLOTS_COMPONENTS } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro/node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/internals'
import { Tooltip } from '@mui/material'

export const TooltipRow = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip title='tooltip'>
      <DATA_GRID_DEFAULT_SLOTS_COMPONENTS.Row {...props} />
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

and then you pass it into slots

```js
<DataGridPro
 {/* Rest of your props */}
  slots={{ row: TooltipRow }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the `GridCellParams` type if you use TypeScript:

```
renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
       <Tooltip title={params.value}>
            <span className="table-cell-trucate">{params.value}</span>
       </Tooltip>
   )
```